# Stripe Checkout charging a card

Tags: php, jquery, stripe-payments

I have this code that works great.

```
<input class="form-control"
   type="number"
   id="custom-donation-amount"
   placeholder="50.00"
   min="0"
   value="50"
   step="10.00"/>
<script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"></script>
<button id="customButton" class="pay-button"> 
    <h4 class="donate-text button">Donate by
    <img src="http://#/testing/credit-card.png" ></h4>
</button>

<script>
  var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
key: 'pk_test_mytestingkey',
image: '',
locale: 'auto',
token: function(token) {
  // Use the token to create the charge with a server-side script.
  // You can access the token ID with `token.id`
}
  });

 $('#customButton').on('click', function(e) {
// Open Checkout with further options
 var amount = $("#custom-donation-amount").val() * 100;
handler.open({
  name: 'Testing',
  description: 'Testing',
  amount: amount
});
e.preventDefault();
});

 // Close Checkout on page navigation
 $(window).on('popstate', function() {
    handler.close();
  });
 </script>
```

It states on the documentation: 
"On your server, grab the Stripe token in the POST parameters submitted by your form. From there, it's one simple API call to charge the card:"
I am trying to CHARGE the card information. Stripe provides the following API call to do that: I am assuming this is a charge.php file?

```
// Set your secret key: remember to change this to your live secret key in production
// See your keys here https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/apikeys
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_mykey");

// Get the credit card details submitted by the form
$token = $_POST['stripeToken'];

// Create the charge on Stripe's servers - this will charge the user's card
try {
  $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
    "amount" => 1000, // amount in cents, again
    "currency" => "usd",
    "source" => $token,
    "description" => "Example charge"
    ));
} catch(\Stripe\Error\Card $e) {
  // The card has been declined
}
```

My question: how do I charge the card using the following code without there being a `<form>` method post, or `<form>` action...? It's using javascript to capture the token. But I don't know how to send that token to a charge.php file... Basically how do I grab that stripe token and initiate the API call? How do I initiate the API call....?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a charge.php file on your server and use $.post to send to the token to the php.

```
// make sure you have the right path to charge.php
// pass the token to the php file with POST, your php is expecting $_POST['stripeToken']
    token: function(token) {
        // Use the token to create the charge with a server-side script.
        // You can access the token ID with `token.id
        $.post( "charge.php", { stripeToken: token.id})
           // check if it worked
          .done(function( data ) {
            console.log( "Card charged: " + data );
          });
    }
```

Your charge.php file, make sure you installed the [Stripe PHP library](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php)

```
<?
// composer require stripe/stripe-php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
// Set your secret key: remember to change this to your live secret key in production
// See your keys here https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/apikeys
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_mykey");

// Get the credit card details submitted by the form
$token = $_POST['stripeToken'];

// Create the charge on Stripe's servers - this will charge the user's card
try {
  $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
    "amount" => 1000, // amount in cents, again
    "currency" => "usd",
    "source" => $token,
    "description" => "Example charge"
    ));
} catch(\Stripe\Error\Card $e) {
  // The card has been declined
}
?>
```

Comment: But where do I have this script running? Just after the input surrounded by <php tags?

Comment: @JonathanSafa the charge.php is a separate file. This script would be in your token:function(token).

Comment: Oh that makes more sense. But what, now, exists in my charge.php file?

Comment: @JonathanSafa what do you mean, "exists"? Not sure to understand your question.

Comment: Sorry, just what script do I put in the "charge.php" file?

Comment: The one I had above that I thought was charge.php is not working.

Comment: It will only work when you POST a "stripeToken" that it can charge.

Comment: Unforunately, that is not working. I made sure I had the right path to that charge.php and it is still not doing anything.

Comment: Do you have a valid test token?

Comment: @JonathanSafa try replacing  $_POST['stripeToken'] by your token and load the charge.php file.

Comment: Sorry, the token is what is created by the credit card input. It's not my testing key...

Comment: So make sure you're using your sk_live_key (replace with yours in the charge file) and try with the token.

Comment: I'm using the sk_test_key, but the one that is provided. It should be showing up in the testing dashboard on Stripe.com, but it's not.

Comment: Are you using a real credit credit card to get the token? Are you using your pk_test_key in your javascript?

Comment: I'm using the provided test credit card, and yes, I've triple checked I've plugged in the right pk keys and test keys

Comment: When you set the $_POST['stripeToken'] to the token you have, what's the error? Do you see any logs in Stripe log?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105514/discussion-between-dontanios-and-jonathan-safa).

Answer (score 0):

Like you say, you need to generate a Stripe token and do a form post. Without a valid token you can not charge the card.

Here's a guide on how to create custom forms with Stripe, including how to generate a token:

https://stripe.com/docs/custom-form

An easier way is to simply embed their ready-to-use checkout:

https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/tutorial

Comment: The problem is using Checkout with the custom integration so that I can have my own custom button. I got it up and running with these basic ones already.

Answer (score 0):

If your are using mamp. [**UPDATE TO MAMP 4**](https://www.mamp.info/en/)
stripes API no longer supports older versions of MAMP.